# Google Compute Engine default firewall port 80

Tags: firewall, google-compute-engine

I've searched around, watched the quick start videos and I'm not seeing many accepted answers.

I'm running Centos 7 on google compute engine. I'm using the default firewall and I've selected to allow http and https traffic during the setup. However I am not able to connect to the webservice and I believe the port is still closed.

here's the output from nmap:

```
Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-01-22 12:04 CST
Nmap scan report for xxxxxx
Host is up (0.072s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT    STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp  open     ssh
646/tcp filtered ldp

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 3.70 seconds
```

Is that correct considering the default firewall rules are to allow http, https, icmp, internal, rdp, and ssh?

One suggestion was to modify iptables rules or stop the service. I tried that and the service was not running.

I've also tried deleting and recreating the default firewall http rule to no effect. My instance has the same tags as the rule as well. I even tried starting another project in case something was wrong at that level. That didn't work either. I also tried another linux distribution in case it was a centos 7 issue, but that gave the same results.

Comment: I've learned that firewalld is the default running firewall in Centos 7 not iptables. I've verified firewalld is not running. However I'm still at a loss as to why I'm unable to connect over port 80.

Answer (score 2):

If no service is running on port 80, nmap will not show it as open. Try to run an httpd service on port 80 and then try nmap, you will see the port as open

Comment: Thanks, That's good information. I didn't know that. It's possible I have a configuration issue with the application. I thought I had this narrowed down to the firewall but that's likely not the case.